# Capture audio from TCS Intercom BUS

Tags: arduino, analog, audio, bus

I try to monitor and capture audio on a TCS Intercom.

There a several projects out there who have revers engineered the bus protocol.
I got it working to see activity on the bus when someone rings the bell and the door buzzer is activated.

Description of the bus:

- 2 wires
- Bits are transmitted via shortening the bus
- Bus carry permanent 24V (DC)
- Voice is transmitted over the same 2 wires

The current setup:

[image]

```c
#include <Arduino.h>
int analogInPin = A0;

int sensorValue = 0;
bool lastone;

volatile uint32_t CMD = 0;
volatile uint8_t lengthCMD = 0;
volatile bool cmdReady;
//volatile bool sendingAktiv;


void analyzeSignal()
{
//  if (sendingAktiv)
//    return;
  static uint32_t curCMD;
  static uint32_t usLast;
  static byte curCRC;
  static byte calCRC;
  static byte curLength;
  static byte cmdIntReady;
  static byte curPos;
  uint32_t usNow = micros();
  uint32_t timeInUS = usNow - usLast;
  usLast = usNow;
  byte curBit = 4;
  if (timeInUS >= 1000 && timeInUS <= 2999)
  {
    curBit = 0;
  }
  else if (timeInUS >= 3000 && timeInUS <= 4999)
  {
    curBit = 1;
  }
  else if (timeInUS >= 5000 && timeInUS <= 6999)
  {
    curBit = 2;
    // curPos = 0;
  }
  else if (timeInUS >= 7000 && timeInUS <= 24000)
  {
    curBit = 3;
    curPos = 0;
    // Serial.println("");
  }

  // Serial.print(curBit);

  if (curPos == 1 && curBit == 2)
    curPos = 0;
  if (curPos == 0)
  {
    if (curBit == 2)
    {
      curPos++;
    }
    curCMD = 0;
    curCRC = 0;
    calCRC = 1;
    curLength = 0;
  }
  else if (curBit == 0 || curBit == 1)
  {
    if (curPos == 1)
    {
      curLength = curBit;
      curPos++;
    }
    else if (curPos >= 2 && curPos <= 17)
    {
      if (curBit)
        bitSet(curCMD, (curLength ? 33 : 17) - curPos);
      calCRC ^= curBit;
      curPos++;
    }
    else if (curPos == 18)
    {
      if (curLength)
      {
        if (curBit)
          bitSet(curCMD, 33 - curPos);
        calCRC ^= curBit;
        curPos++;
      }
      else
      {
        curCRC = curBit;
        cmdIntReady = 1;
      }
    }
    else if (curPos >= 19 && curPos <= 33)
    {
      if (curBit)
        bitSet(curCMD, 33 - curPos);
      calCRC ^= curBit;
      curPos++;
    }
    else if (curPos == 34)
    {
      curCRC = curBit;
      cmdIntReady = 1;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    curPos = 0;
  }
  if (cmdIntReady)
  {
    cmdIntReady = 0;
    curPos = 0;
    if (curCRC == calCRC)
    {
      cmdReady = 1;
      lengthCMD = curLength;
      CMD = curCMD;
      // sendeACK();
    }
    curCMD = 0;
  }
}


void printHEX(uint32_t DATA)
{
  uint8_t numChars = lengthCMD ? 8 : 4;
  uint32_t mask = 0x0000000F;
  mask = mask << 4 * (numChars - 1);
  for (uint32_t i = numChars; i > 0; --i)
  {
    Serial.print(((DATA & mask) >> (i - 1) * 4), HEX);
    mask = mask >> 4;
  }
}



void setup()
{

  //pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  //digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello from Arduino");
}

void loop()
{
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);

  if (sensorValue >= 400 && lastone == true)
  {
    lastone = false;
    analyzeSignal();
  }
  else if (sensorValue < 400 && lastone == false)
  {
    lastone = true;
    analyzeSignal();
  }

  if (cmdReady)
  {
    cmdReady = 0;
    printHEX(CMD);
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

Now i want to capture the audio that is transmitted over the bus.
I dont know enough about "buses" and transmitting additional "data" over the bus while it is also used as power supply.

I have that feeling/read that i need to decouple the DC on the bus with a capacitor and another Voltage divider to get a bias voltage to 2.5V to get the analog voice that i can feed into another arduino analog input.

Can some one point me into the right direction?

As first step i want just to capture the audio in the arduino and write it via the Serial connection to my computer. (as raw bytes or what ever that i can then convert with ffmpeg or what ever to listen to it.)

But i have never done something like this.

In short Terms:

1. How to get the analog audio from the BUS (electronic)
2. How to capture the audio (software)

Thanks in advance.
Any help/hint is welcomed!

Links/Information/Projects about the TCS BUS:

- https://github.com/Syralist/tcs-monitor
- https://github.com/atc1441/TCSintercomArduino
- https://github.com/peteh/doorman
- https://hackaday.com/2019/10/27/reverse-engineering-a-two-wire-intercom/

---

EDIT: I would solve like this. Use a second Voltage divided behind the first one, to drop the voltage to 2.5V and use then a capacitor in series to decouple the Audio signal from the supply voltage:

[image]

Makes this sense?
Note: The resistors are calculated with a online tool: https://www.redcrab-software.com/de/Rechner/Elektro/Spannungsteiler

[image]